# React not properly updating screen after state is set following a post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a code block for submitting a log entry on a particular date.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import { Keyboard } from "react-native";

export default class PostForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    body: "",
    date: new Date(),
  };

  setBody = (newBody) => {
    this.setState({ body: newBody });
  };

  setDate = (event, newDate) => {
    this.setState({ date: newDate });
  };

  postEntry = () => {
    if (this.state.body.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onSubmit({
      body: this.state.body,
      date: this.state.date.toISOString(),
    });
    this.setState({
      body: "",
      date: new Date(),
    });
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.vertContainer}>
        <View style={styles.horContainer}>
          <DateTimePicker
            style={styles.dateTime}
            value={this.state.date}
            accentColor="#E2AFDE"
            onChange={this.setDate}
          />
          <Pressable style={styles.post} onPress={() => this.postEntry()}>
            <Ionicons
              style={styles.postIcon}
              name={"arrow-forward-outline"}
              size={30}
            />
          </Pressable>
        </View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="What happened?"
          multiline={true}
          value={this.state.body}
          onChangeText={(newText) => this.setBody(newText)}
          maxLength={378}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  vertContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  horContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    verticalAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  input: {
    width: "100%",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    padding: 15,
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
  post: {
    backgroundColor: "#E2AFDE",
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 50,
  },
  postIcon: {
    color: "white",
  },
  dateTime: {},
});
```

For some reason, when the pressable is pressed, it doesn't cause the state to be updated to reflect the empty body and new Date. I am currently using setState in postEntry, but when I have console logged after the fact, the state doesn't properly get updated (and in turn isn't reflected in the actual view)

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import PostForm from "../components/PostForm";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addEntry } from "../redux/actions";

class PostScreen extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (form) => {
    this.props.addEntry(form);
    this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <PostForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></PostForm>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
});

export default connect(null, { addEntry: addEntry })(PostScreen);
```

Weirdly I've noticed it takes to clicks for it to automatically clear.

Comment: Are you sure the `onSubmit()` is defined in the parent component? Please post the code where you use `<PostForm />`.

Comment: @kiuQ I just added it to the original, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

All fixed - I ended up moving a lot of the logic into the PostScreen.

PostForm:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import { Keyboard } from "react-native";

export default class PostForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    body: "",
    date: new Date(),
  };

  setBody = (newBody) => {
    this.setState({ body: newBody });
  };

  setDate = (event, newDate) => {
    this.setState({ date: newDate });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
    this.setState({
      body: "",
      date: new Date(),
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.vertContainer}>
        <View style={styles.horContainer}>
          <DateTimePicker
            style={styles.dateTime}
            value={this.state.date}
            accentColor="#828A95"
            onChange={this.setDate}
          />
          <Pressable style={styles.post} onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Ionicons
              style={styles.postIcon}
              name={"arrow-forward-outline"}
              size={30}
            />
          </Pressable>
        </View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="What happened?"
          multiline={true}
          value={this.state.body}
          onChangeText={this.setBody}
          maxLength={378}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  vertContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  horContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    verticalAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  input: {
    width: "100%",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    padding: 15,
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
  post: {
    backgroundColor: "#828A95",
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 50,
  },
  postIcon: {
    color: "white",
  },
  dateTime: {},
});
```

PostScreen:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import PostForm from "../components/PostForm";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addEntry } from "../redux/actions";

class PostScreen extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (form) => {
    if (form.body.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.addEntry({
      body: form.body,
      date: form.date.toISOString(),
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <PostForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></PostForm>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
});

export default connect(null, { addEntry: addEntry })(PostScreen);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
<Pressable style={styles.post} onPress={this.postEntry}>
```

I think it is work fine.

Comment: You should test the code before uploading it here. Your words say you are not sure of the answer